# Get the id from the table based on the condition

Tags: sql, mysql, database, subquery, common-table-expression

I have 2 table t1 & t2 both table has 3 columns id,status,run_date.

Find the id from t1 that

1. have different status in t2 than in the t1 AND run_date in t2 is older than t1
2. do not exist in t2

3)In t2 table there may be multiple occurrences of the same id, with different run dates
for run_date comparison, please take the most recent occurrence only.

I tried the below query, but im getting error at the 2nd where condition (status difference)as subquery is returning multiple rows. Please help in solving this.

Error: [UNSUPPORTED_SUBQUERY_EXPRESSION_CATEGORY.MUST_AGGREGATE_CORRELATED_SCALAR_SUBQUERY] Unsupported subquery expression: Correlated scalar subqueries must be aggregated to return at most one row.; line 11 pos 31;

```
WITH most_recent_id AS(
    select id,max(run_date) as latest_run_date
    from t2
    group by id
)

SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN most_recent_id ON t1.id = most_recent_id.id
WHERE (most_recent_id.id IS NULL) OR 
(t1.status <> (select status from t2 a where a.id=t1.id and   a.run_date=most_recent_id.latest_run_date)
AND most_recent_id.latest_run_date < t1.run_date)
```

Comment: Please try ```select TOP 1 status``` instead of ```select status ``` in the subquery.

Answer (score -1):

You could start with a non-matching LEFT JOIN to get the latest rows per id in t2:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.status, t2.run_date
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t2 t2later ON
  t2.id = t2later.id
  AND t2.run_date < t2later.run_date
WHERE t2later.run_date IS NULL
```

You could then use this as a subquery in a second non-matching LEFT JOIN to get the t1 rows that don't match the inverse of your criteria:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t2.id, t2.status, t2.run_date
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t2 t2later ON
      t2.id = t2later.id
      AND t2.run_date < t2later.run_date
    WHERE t2later.run_date IS NULL
    ) t2max ON
    t1.id = t2max.id
    AND (t1.status = t2max.status OR t1.run_date < t2max.run_date)
WHERE t2max.id IS NULL
```